# Is the language $\{a^n b^m \mid 2n + 3m \le 1000 \}$ regular?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, pumping-lemma

We have a language  $$ L = \{a^n b^m \mid 2n + 3m \le 1000 \} $$

Is this language regular?

I'm trying to disprove this using the Pumping Lemma, but it didn't work.

assume I say x = $x=a^{h}$ and $y=a^{t}$ and $z =a^{n-t-h}b^m$

if I say `i = 0` everything is okay because $L =a^{n-t}b^m$ and `2(n-t) + 3m <= 1000`

if I say `i = 2`  $L =a^{n+t}b^m$ and `2(n+t) + 3m <= 1000` because I'm not sure about `t` value.

I think it didn't work. Is this language regular? How can I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is finite and, as such, it is regular (all finite languages are regular).

To see that the language is finite, notice that the maximum length of each word in $L$ is upper bounded by $500$.
Indeed, if $w \in L$, and $n$ (resp. $m$) is the number of $a$s (resp. $b$s) in $w$:

$$
2|w| = 2(n + m) \le 2n+ 3m \le 1000.
$$

Comment: What if 2n - 3m <= 1000? Is this language irregular?

Comment: For the original language, the pumping Lemma didn’t prove anything, for a reason. For your proposed language, the pumping Lemma should work.

Comment: @narges Hint: you can rewrite $2n-3m \le 1000$ as $n \le 500 + (3/2)m$. Can you come up with a word in the language that can be be "pumped" enough times to violate that inequality?

Comment: @Steven Thanks a lot.